# How to Receive Events from an Application running on a Remote Desktop using pywinauto

Tags: python, automation, desktop, rdp, pywinauto

The automation using pywinauto is working fine in the Remote Desktop Applications with mouse/keyboard and send_keys events.
But I need to track the events generated from the application running on remote desktop to build conditional use case.

**For Example**, Let's say, I have an excel file opened in the remote desktop and using the pywinauto and send_keys function I can able to write some text in some predefined cell (using mouse co-ordinates) of that file.

But when I'm clicking the exit button in excel it will pop up an window asking if I want to save the excel before closing. I need to catch that event in pywinauto.

[image]

**pywinauto is running on my local and all the tasks are going to happen on remote desktop (win32).**

**Note: I don't want to tackle this situation with mouse click on predefined co-ordinates because in-real, based the popup window of my application, I need to do some other tasks.**

Answer (score 0):

Remote desktop doesn't pass any GUI elements info to local machine. So you have to run pywinauto script on a remote machine. All necessary recipes are here: [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html).

Comment: Thanks for you response. Unfortunately, due to security restriction, nothing can be installed in the remote machine.

Comment: Allowing Remote Desktop is already enough security hole. You have to explain your security guys that it’s stupid way. If you have no enough authority to push your IT department, I can suggest packing the script to executable and copy it to remote machine without installing Python. But you may face portability side effects with comtypes cache if you use “uia” backend.